# How to count the number of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits in a string?

Tags: c++, string, uppercase, counting, lowercase

I want to write a program in C++ which gets a string from the user and outputs the number of uppercase letters, lowercase letters and digits.

e.g. for input "aKb12CD34" the result should be 2 lowercase letters, 3 uppercase letters, and 4 digits.

Comment: Please try and learn  c++ at sites like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/ If you have difficulties then you can post here.

Comment: Use an array of lower case letters and an array of of upper case letters.  Search array.  If letter exists in array, increment the appropriate counter.  Or use `std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't get what you mean in your method, could you please clarify your method? Thanks ;)

Comment: `const char lower_case[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}; if (strchr(&lowercase[0], my_variable) != NULL) ++quantity_lower_case_letters;`.  Or `if (tolower(my_variable)) ++quantity_lower_case_letters;`.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << " Enter text: ";
    string s;
    if(getline(cin, s))
    {
        size_t count_lower = count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
               [](unsigned char ch) { return islower(ch); });
        cout << "lowers: " << count_lower ;

        size_t count_upper = count_if(s.begin(), s.end(),    
               [](unsigned char ch) { return isupper(ch); });
        cout << "uppers: " << count_upper ;

        size_t count_digit = count_if(s.begin(), s.end(),    
               [](unsigned char ch) { return isdigit(ch); });
        cout << "digits: " << count_digit ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Especially given that this has no explanation, and uses lambda expressions, I'm not sure it qualifies as "easy for newbies to use/learn".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - regarding this and *other* submissions, it's kind of a tradition in SO to give overly complex and/or dangerous solutions to homework assignments, especially if the OP makes no attempt on his side... ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() 
{
int upper = 0, lower = 0,digit=0,special=0;
char ch[80];
int i;

printf("\nEnter The String : ");
gets(ch);

for(i = 0; ch[i]!='\0';i++)

{
if (ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')
upper++;
else if (ch[i] >= 'a' && ch[i] <= 'z')
lower++;
else if(ch[i] >='0' && ch[i] <='9')
digit++;
else if(ch[i]!=' ')
special++;
}


printf("\nUppercase Letters : %d", upper);
printf("\nLowercase Letters : %d", lower);
printf("\nDigits : %d", digit);
printf("\nSpecial Characters : %d",special);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly better C++ approach is to let the compiler figure out the right datatypes to use:

```
auto count_lower =
   count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](auto ch) { return islower(ch); });
```

And so on...