# Program that counts the number of types of letters in a paragraph, C++

Tags: c++

What I want is to have a multiple-line text input, and to be able to count the number of lower-case letters, upper-case letters, periods, commas, spaces, line-breaks, and other characters in the input.

I am trying to use just one string with getline for inputs in a while loop with a running count for each punctuation category.

I just don't know how to actually figure out how many of each character type there are in each line. Given a string, how do I count the number of each type?

Here is my code so far (obviously incomplete):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "This program takes any number of sentences as inputs. " << endl;
    cout << "It will count the number of lower-case letters and upper-case letters. " << endl;
    cout << "It will also count the number of periods, exclamation marks, spaces, end-lines, etc. " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Please type your text, pressing enter whenever you wish to end a line. " << endl;
    cout << "Use the EOF key (CTRL + Z on Windows) when you are finished. " << endl;

    string InputString; // This is the string that will be used iteratively, for each line.

    int NumberOfLowerCase = 0;
    int NumberOfUpperCase = 0;
    int NumberOfSpaces = 0;     // spaces
    int NumberOfTabs = 0;       // tabs
    int NumberOfPeriods = 0;    // periods
    int NumberOfCommas = 0;     // commas
    int NumberOfOtherChars = 0; // other characters
    int NumberOfEnters = 0;     // end of line, will be incremented each loop

    do {
        getline(cin, InputString);   // input
        cout << InputString << endl; // filler just to test the input 
        NumberOfLowerCase = NumberOfLowerCase + 0   // I don't know what I should be adding
                                                    // (obviously not zero, that's just a filler)
    } while (!cin.eof() && cin.good());

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check for each character in a switch or with if-statements. Increment the corresponding counter accordingly.

Comment: I didn't down vote you but there are a number of questions that already address this, and probably many resources on the web. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948722/how-to-code-a-c-program-which-counts-the-number-of-uppercase-letters-lowercas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the number of unique characters, use a [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)! You can push all of your characters into the set and then just check how big the set is and you'll be good to go!

If you actually want to know how many of each character there are you can use a [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (which in fact uses a set under the hood!). With the map, given some character `c`, you could do

```
std::map<char, int> counter;
//do stuff...
counter[c]++; //increment the number of character c we've found
//do more stuff...
std::cout << "Found " << counter['A'] << " A's!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: @TerrenceTown if this was the answer you were looking for, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, let me know what else you want to know!

Comment: Well I don't really understand it but I can tell you know what you're doing :D

Comment: @TerrenceTown Where are you confused? Let me know so I can explain more in the answer!

Comment: @scohe001, since the ordering of `std::map` isn't needed, this could be more efficiently solved with `std::unordered_map` if OP uses large paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

See [these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) helpful functions. Here what you would do:

```
std::string s = /*...*/;

for(auto c : s) {
    if(std::islower(c))      ++NumberOfLowerCase;
    else if(std::isupper(c)) ++NumberOfUpperCase;
    else if(c == ' ')        ++NumberOfSpaces;
    else if(c == '\t')       ++NumberOfTabs;
    else if(c == '.')        ++NumberOfPeriods;
    else if(c == ',')        ++NumberOfCommas;
    else                     ++NumberOfOtherChars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example I wrote very quickly. Of course there are better ways of doing it, but this should give you an idea of how you could do that. One question: Are you reading from a file or from an istream directly from the console?

```
int lowerCase = 0;
int upperCase = 0;
int spaces = 0;     // spaces
int tabs = 0;       // tabs
int newLines = 0;   // end of line, will be incremented each loop
int periods = 0;    // periods
int commas = 0;     // commas
int otherChars = 0;

// read from istream, char by char
for (char ch; cin >> noskipws >> ch;) {
    // test which classification or char ch is and increment its count
    if (islower(ch))
        ++lowerCase;
    else if (isupper(ch))
        ++upperCase;
    else if (ch == ' ')
        ++spaces;
    else if (ch == '\t')
        ++tabs;
    else if (ch == '\n')
        ++newLines;
    else if (ch == '.')
        ++periods;
    else if (ch == ',')
        ++commas;
    else
        ++otherChars;
}

cout << "Number of characters of each type:\n";

cout << "lowerCase:\t" << lowerCase << '\n'
     << "upperCase:\t" << upperCase << '\n'
     << "spaces:\t\t" << spaces << '\n'
     << "tabs:\t\t" << tabs << '\n'
     << "periods:\t" << periods << '\n'
     << "commas:\t\t" << commas << '\n'
     << "newLines:\t" << newLines << '\n'
     << "otherChars:\t" << otherChars << '\n';
```