# How to find letters from a string using an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to decipher a sentence. For every word found I want to add one to a counter. I have a nested for loop and when the user types in the sentence one for loop is going to cycle through through the sentence ( int i = 0) and the other (int j = 0) will cycle through the array and when they find corresponding letters. I thought what I did would have made sense but for some reason it is not working. Here a re pieces of my code that deals with this section. Thank you in advance :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
string alphebet[26] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

string sentence;
cin >> sentence;
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < alphebet; j++){
        if (sentence[i] == alphebet[j]){
            counter_letters = counter_letters + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  What is your question?  "it is not working" does not inform, so we can not help.

Comment: `j` goes from `0` to `alphabet`, you probably wanted `0` to `26`

Comment: There is a `isupper` function: https://linux.die.net/man/3/isupper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your `alphebet` to a char array like such `char alphabet[26]`. Then you need to use `getline(cin, sentence)` to get an entire line of input like 'Hello World' whereas `cin << sentence` only gets the first word. Next you need to convert the string to uppercase so that it matches your `alphebet` later, do this with `transform(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), sentence.begin(), ::toupper);`. After that be sure to initialize your variable `counter_letters`. As a side note you didn't need to do `counter_letters = counter_letters + 1;` you could do `counter_letters += 1;` or `counter_letters++;` or `++counter_letters;`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char alphebet[26] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    string sentence;
    getline(cin,sentence);
    transform(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), sentence.begin(), ::toupper);

    int counter_letters = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
            if (sentence[i] == alphebet[j]){
                counter_letters++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << counter_letters << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey What if I want to use " sentence = toupper(sentence); " ... For some reason toupper won't work this way.. Why?

Comment: `int toupper ( int c );` You're using it wrong, it takes a single character `int c` and returns another character in the form of an int.

Comment: That's why you have to use `transform`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about your problem here but one proposition is that you might be entering space in the input . cin doesnot read spaces and so you code might not work properly

if that's not the problem , please see the link below to count uppercase,lowercase letters in a string
[How to code a C++ program which counts the number of uppercase letters, lowercase letters and integers in an inputted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948722/how-to-code-a-c-program-which-counts-the-number-of-uppercase-letters-lowercas)

Comment: Should be a comment